# Does 'void (*)(int)' the same with 'void (^)(int)'?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Today, I'm working on a callback pass from C++ to Objective-c method.
Finally, I worked it out, but a few code confuse me.
In Objective-c, people ordinary use block to implement a callback, a block declare looks like this:

> returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes)

I also learned about C++ callback, a same type callback defined like this:

> returnType (*funcName)(parameterTypes)

When I passed a callback from C++ to Objective-c, compiler warning me:

```
"Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (^)(int)' with an rvalue of type 'void (*)(int)"
```

Finally, I changed `^` to `*`, it works.  I wondering to know, what's the difference between `^` and `*` in definition, is that have the same behavior?

Comment: In c++ `^` is the bitwise XOR

Comment: @DimChtz Just as it is in Objective-C.  Context makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is a block:

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes)
```

This is a function pointer:

```
returnType (*funcName)(parameterTypes)
```

They aren't compatible.

Comment: What I want to know is the difference of runtime behavior

Comment: @DelphiQin You didn't ask that, however there is plenty of documentation online about both concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C and C++ do not have callable blocks.  Apparently, however, some compilers for those languages do implement the feature as an extension.  Some of the docs I see suggest that it's an Apple extension to Objective C, too, but inasmuch as Objective C is little used outside the Apple world, that may be a distinction without a difference.

In whatever language, if you implement a callback as a function, then you must present that callback to the intended caller via a function pointer, and the caller must be prepared to accept it in that form.  On the other hand, if you implement a callback as a block then you must present it to the caller via a block pointer, and the caller must be prepared to accept *that* form.  The two are not interchangeable, and they have different syntaxes, which you have presented.  It would be possible to design a mechanism that could accept both forms, however, via separate parameters or altogether separate registration functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C blocks (`^`) are incompatible with function pointers (`*`).
Compared to function pointers, they have the benefit of being able to capture values and variables from the surrounding context (they are *closures*).

It's easy enough to write a wrapper that calls a function pointer from a block:

```
typedef int (*funptr)(int);
typedef int (^funblock)(int);


int use_block_callback(int y, funblock fb)
{
    return fb(y);
}

int use_funptr_callback(int y, funptr f)
{
     return use_block_callback(y, ^ int (int x) { return f(x); }); 
}

int add_one(int x) { return x + 1; }

int foo(int x)
{
    return use_funptr_callback(23, add_one);
}

// Or
int (*some_pointer)(int) = add_one;
int (^some_block)(int) = ^ int (int x) { return some_pointer(x); }
```

(["Programming with Objective-C" about blocks.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me. :)